# Develop sales funnel UI using highcharts and react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

So here is what has to be developed. It is a sales funnel that tapers down based on each conversion stage. Now using highcharts and react the UI needs to be implemented.

I want to know as to how I would use the customization features of highcharts to create the taper effect.

[Wireframe for sales funnel UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNqcd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNqcd.png)

Code I wrote for rendering first chart is as follows:

```
const HighCharts = () => {
  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: "column",
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        "Inquiries-Target(1800)",
        "Responded ",
        "Connected/Reached",
        "Follow-ups",
        "Sales Qualified(SQL)",
        "Requirement Analysis",
        "Proposals",
        "Final Consideration",
        "Closed",
      ],
    },
    title: {
      text: "My chart",
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: "percent",
      },
      series: {
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Pending",
        data: [300, 1100, 900, 875, 675, 500, 300, 200, 100],
      },
      {
        name: "Closed",
        data: [1500, 500, 500, 325, 325, 300, 150, 110, 120],
      },
    ],
  };

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};
```

[image: UI output]

There is a funnel chart option but it is not delivering on the customization I intend on performing. So I would like to know how to approach this issue I am facing

Link to funnel chart demo - [Here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/funnel/dark-unica)

Answer (score 1):

The default funnel chart in Highcharts doesn't seem to be the best solution for your design. The easiest way to build such a chart is to use a combination of `area` and `column` series.

For example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: null,
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        fillColor: '#d9d9d9',
        data: [
            [-1, 100],
            [3, 50]
        ]
    }, {
        type: 'area',
        fillColor: '#fff',
        zIndex: 2,
        data: [
            [-1, 0],
            [3, 50]
        ]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        color: '#b7b4b4',
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [20, 15, 15, 10],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y}%'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        data: [100, 100, 100, 100],
        borderColor: '#000',
        color: 'transparent'
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            pointPlacement: 'between',
            stacking: 'normal',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false,
        max: 100,
        reversedStacks: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        visible: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qu34djhc/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Hey so thanks a lot for this , however on hover I need the following effect on hover and right now the hover part looks confusing , how do I reconfigure it ?
[dashboard UI](https://ibb.co/HdTKrtJ)

Comment: Hi @Sidharth Gopalakrishnan, You can disable the hover effect and `enableMouseTracking` for the area series and also use tooltip positioner function. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ua17pqh/